# shutil.move() move from directory program is ran from, to target folder

Tags: python, if-statement, operating-system, shutil

I'm having trouble getting shutil.move() working properly, I can use os.getcwd() to utilize the working directory, however I'm missing the '' that comes after the directory and before the file name, I've tried inputting a ` + '\' after the directory but it doesnt recognise this.

Error is below, missing the '' after GUI and before test.pdf.
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Z:\PyCharm\GUItest.pdf'

```
output_folder = input()
source_dir = os.getcwd()
if os.path.isfile(f'{output_folder}test.pdf'):
    print('File already exists, saved to your Z drive!')
    shutil.move(f'{source_dir} test.pdf', 'Z:\')  # needs to look in directory the program is ran from.
else:
    shutil.move(f'{source_dir} test.pdf', output_folder)  # same as above.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local files start with `.\` in Windows.
Try `shutil.move(r'.\test.pdf', r'Z:\test.pdf')`

Comment: I've edited my question, similar problem.

Comment: @Chaotic.Python Have you added the 'r' before the path string?  I tried something similar and `shutil.move(rf'{source_dir}\test.pdf', output_folder)` seems to work.
The error seems to imply that the format is correct, just the file is missing.

Comment: Ah no, I was using an f string and somehow completely forgot to use the "r". Thanks for the feedback Connor!

Comment: @Chaotic.Python Hey, I learned about the f string method, so it's a win-win